# Managing Linux user authentication and filesystem permissions from Java web application

Tags: java, linux, unix, jaas, pam

I need to authenticate users on a linux system via a Java web application, using both local users and LDAP/AD.
For what is my understanding, JAAS would be perfect for this, except I need those users to manage files and directories using their account, not Tomcat.

Is this possible?